# Filtering the null item from a 2d array as well as multiply another object with some value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

```
var data = [[100, 35.60], [110, 42.56], [120, 48.4], [200, null]]
```

This is the array, and I want to multiply the first index of the inner array chunk by 2 and filter the null result as well so that the result be like

```
data = [[200, 35.60], [220, 42.56], [240, 48.4]]
```

I can do this by using normal for loop but how can I achieve this with the help of high order functions?

Comment: " want to multiply the first index of the inner array chunk by 2 and filter the null result" Well that sounds like 3 clearly defined parts: 1) multiple the first element of each array by 2, 2) chunk the array by 2, 3) filter out the nulls. Which of these 3 parts are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to validate nil using filter, and later use map

```
var data = [[100, 35.60], [110, 42.56], [120, 48.4], [200, nil]]


var newArray = data.filter{
    if let item1 = $0[0] , let item2 = $0[1]{
        return true
    }
    return false
}.map { item -> [Double] in

    return [item[0]!*2 , item[1]!]
}

print(newArray)

[[200.0, 35.6], [220.0, 42.56], [240.0, 48.4]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much mate... The code is working exactly like I wanted. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score -1):

Try this code bellow

```
    let data = [[100, 35.60], [110, 42.56], [120, 48.4], [200, nil]]
    let array = data.filter({ $0[1] != nil }).map { [($0[0] ?? 0)*2 , $0[1] ?? 0] }
    print(array)
```